# SNOW ODBC trying to get to the data in the screenshot but it just wouldn't give it(I have access to the data/permissions)

Tags: python, sql, odbc, servicenow

I want to avoid having to manually extract the report as much as possible. I have already done so and it really isn't the most efficient solution. I hope someone knows the right way to do this and can help. I would honestly sincerely appreciate it!

[That's what I am trying to get out with SNOW ODBC to then place in my databank, however, it just can't figure out how to get to it with SNOW ODBC]

[image: 1]

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. As it is now, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I would like to gather the exact same data which is showed in the screenshot (lower part) with sql statements via the odbc from SNOW

Comment: Do you mean I should try posting a screenshot from the ODBC?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Run a [scheduled report](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/sandiego/app_store_learnv2_reportanalytics_sandiego_reporting_and_analytics/app_store_learnv2_reportanalytics_sandiego_data_visualization/app_store_learnv2_reportanalytics_sandiego_scheduled_reports), which is a built-in function in ServiceNow to send the report via email

Or [setup the ODBC](https://docs.servicenow.com/en-US/bundle/sandiego-application-development/page/integrate/odbc-driver/concept/c_ODBCDriver.html) with your application and run the query:

```
SELECT number, value, duration FROM incident_metric;
```